# bibtex issue : Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "birks"

Tags: database, bibtex, citing

I'm having an issue using bibtex with pdflatex. Here is the file biblio.bib I'm using (with this exact format) :

```
@Book{physiqueNucleaire,
author = "Claude le Sech and Christian Ngô",
title = "Physique Nucléaire, des Quarks aux Applications",
year = "2010",
publisher = "Dunod"}

@Book{birks,
author = "J.B. Birks",
title = "The theory and Practice of Scintillation Counting",
year = "1964",
publisher = "Pergamon Presse Ltd."}
```

In the list of packages (at the beginning of the main file report.tex) :

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

And the main file section where the bibliography is "called" :

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

In a chapter file defined before this last section, I use the \cite{physiqueNucleaire} command and it works perfectly. In an another chapter file, I use the \cite{birks} command, and the bibtex compiler (if this makes any sense) respond :

```
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "birks"
```

I am aware I need to call the different latex commands in this order, and I tried it without any success :

```
pdflatex report.tex
bibtex report.tex
pdflatex report.tex
pdflatex report.tex
```

I also tried to delete all the files generated through the compilations (at least all the files contained in the .tex file folder - are there any elsewhere ?)

Are there rules or specific places where we can call the \cite{} command ? How much rigorous is the format in the .bib file needs to be ?

I already used Latex before exactly the same way and it worked succesfully, could this have something to do with the environnement ? I "migrated" from ubuntu 11.04 and gedit with the Latex plugin to KUbuntu 11.04 using kate.

Any help will be rewarded with a virtual hug,

Mortuis

Comment: Could it be that the accentuated letters in the `physiqueNucleaire` entry corrupts the following entry, making it unavailable? What happens when you move the `birks` entry up?

Comment: I just tried moving the birks' entry up, same error occur. Worth a try !

Comment: Try with a minimal example : just `\cite{birks}` in your document body, and just the `birks` entry in your `biblio.bib` file, nothing else. Then add the other entries in the `biblio.bib` file. Then add the other `\cite{...}` commands in the document body. Whenever that breaks, you will know where to look the culprit for. From my (small) experience with BibTeX, this kind of error usually comes from a malformed entry in the bib file that corrupts the rest.

Comment: Regardless of the 'birks' problem, you can't have accented characters in a file that will be used with `bibtex`. Change 'ô' to {\^o} and 'é' to {\'e}.  Or, better, switch to `biber` (which requires, however, `biblatex`).

Answer (score 2):

The error may be caused by something else in your text. I tried this short example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{physiqueNucleaire}
\cite{birks}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

with your two references in the `bib` file and it compiled w/o a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try `\bibliography{absolute/path/to/.bib}`, because I have the same problem while I type like this `\bibliography{~/.../path/to/.bib}`

Comment: Please have a look to https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.